# Calling Fetch in React App.js with Prop Drilling

Tags: reactjs, http, fetch

So I would like to call fetch from a function (submitURL) in App.js. If I create "componentDidMount()" in App.js and call fetch there, it works, but not from submitURL. I believe this is because submitURL is called via prop drilling. How would I call fetch from submitURL?

---

App.js

```
class App extends Component {
  state = {
      channelURL: '',
      videos: []
    }

  submitURL = (value) => {

    fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1')
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(json => console.log(json))

    this.setState({
      channelURL: value
    });
  }

  render() {
    console.log(this.state)

    return (
      <div className="App">
        <h1> Title </h1>
        <Channel submitURL={this.submitURL} url={this.state.channelURL}/>
        <Videos videos={this.state.videos}/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

---

Channel.js

```
class Channel extends Component {
  state = {
    value: this.props.url
  }

  handleChange = (e) => {
    this.setState({
      value: e.target.value
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1> Enter Channel URL </h1>
        <form onSubmit={this.props.submitURL.bind(this, this.state.value)}>
          URL: <input type="text" name="url" value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange}/>
          <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Channel;
```

Comment: check this and let me know if any problem after this https://stackoverflow.com/a/58636609/6544460

Comment: i checked your code now can you explain me your requirement please?

Answer (score 1):

```
submitURL = (value) => {

    fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1')
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(json => this.setState({
      channelURL: json
    }))
  }
```

Comment: Fetch does not seem to be called when I run this. I added a "console.log(this.state)" after the fetch call to see if the state updated and it did not.

Comment: if you check on network tab, is there any request made? if yes, then fetch is succesfully called. And, `setState` work asynchronously, if you want to check the updated state right after `setState` then add callback function `this.setState({
      channelURL: json
    }, () => console.log(this.state))`. This will ensure to print the state after it finished updating

Comment: I just checked and surprisingly, yes, there was a fetch request made. Its status, however, is "canceled". Also, adding the code Nicky had did not log any additional state.